# How to have a Scheduler at the parent job for all child jobs?

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, threadpool, spring-batch

The situation is as follows. I want to have a parent job with some common properties, an ExecutionListener and a Scheduler. There could be many child jobs that extend from my parent job. Now the Scheduler at the parent needs to read all the child jobIds, pick-up the corresponding cron expressions from a DB and execute/schedule the jobs. Something of the sort:

```
                   <job id="job1">
                      <step id="step1">
                         <tasklet><bean id="some bean"/></tasklet>
                      </step>
                   </job>

                   <bean id="myjob1" parent="parentJob">
                        <property name="job" value="job1"/>
                        <property name="jobId" value=123/>
                    </bean>
```

Similarly, there could be more jobs extending "parentJob". Now at the "parentJob" I am trying to do something as follows:

```
                 scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();  
                 scheduler.setPoolSize(5);
                 scheduler.schedule(new TriggerTask(), new Cron(some expr)
```

The challenge at hand is, the child jobIds are getting lost. At most the last child's jobId is getting picked up but not the others. NOTE: new TriggerTask() is an inner class that implements 'Runnable'.

Somehow I think I am messing up something bad with threads.
Could someone please assist or provide some directions on how this could be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: What is the scheduler used for?  Launching the jobs or something else?

Comment: @MichaelMinella Yes, for launching the jobs. Preferably all the jobs that have 'parentJob' as the parent.

Comment: A job cannot launch itself.  By design job orchestration is outside of what Spring Batch does.  That scheduler code would live outside of the job itself.